# Why won't webbrowser module open my html file in my browser

Tags: python

I am using the python webbrowser module to try and open a html file. I added a short thing to get code from a website to view, allowing me to store a web-page incase I ever need to view it without wifi, for instance a news article or something else.

The code itself is fairly short so far, so here it is:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import re
webcheck = re.compile('^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+)([\/a-zA-Z0-9#\-_]+\/?)*$')
#Valid URL Check
while True:
    url = input('URL (MUST HAVE HTTP://): ')
    check = webcheck.search(url)
    groups = list(check.groups())
    if check != None:
        for group in groups:
            if group == 'https://':
                groups.remove(group)
            elif group.count('/') > 0:
                groups.append(group.replace('/', '--'))
                groups.remove(group)
        filename = ''.join(groups) + '.html'
        break
#Getting Website Data
reply = req.get(url)
soup = bs(reply.text, 'html.parser')
#Writing Website
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(reply.text)
#Open Website
webbrowser.open(filename)
webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

I added `webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')` so that I knew the module was working, which it was, as it did open up youtube.
However, `webbrowser.open(filename)` doesn't do anything, yet it returns ***True*** if I define it as a variable and print it.
The html file itself has a period in the name, but I don't think that should matter as I have made a file without it as the name and it wont run.

Does webbrowser need special permissions to work?
I'm not sure what to do as I've removed characters from the filename and even showed that the module is working by opening youtube.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the `webbrowser` documentation:

> Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable.

So it seems that webbrowser can't do what you want.  Why did you expect that it would?

Comment: I was googling how to do this, and I found [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-html-files-open-in-chrome-using-python/) that showed how this would work. I was assuming it was something wrong with my code. What does not portable mean? Is it not supported on a mac?

Comment: @blankblanks Does your filename begin with `file:///`, as it does in the tutorial?

Comment: No, I used the second instance as stated in the bottom of the tutorial saying that you can just use 'blank.html' which I do have, as long as its in the same parent-folder.

Comment: I have also tried adding the file:// and file:/// and it has opened in my browser but the page says can't be reached because the file is moved or unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

adding file:// + full path name does the trick for any wondering